# How do I add a always on duplex receptacle under sink on same circuit as switched garbage disposal

Tags: electrical, receptacle, garbage-disposal, water-filtration

[image]Garbage disposer and dishwasher each have their own breaker. Garbage disposer hardwired into a toggle switch above sink that powers it on/off.

My filter and faucet needs somewhere to be plugged in and power not interrupted by the disposer switch.[image]

Additional photos: https://imgur.com/a/8MShyGG

Comment: OK, what's your question? Please take the [tour], then read through the [help] on how to ask a good question, then [edit] this to ask a question. Also, while it's a good thing that the cover plate is there, that single screw into the back of the cabinet is a reasonably strong indicator that something isn't wired up to code.

Comment: @FreeMan, I've updated the post. Thanks! I haven't modified the current setup any - I would assume it came from the builder like that, especially since the garbage disposal is hardwired in - seems like a cost saving thing a cookie cutter developer would do.

Comment: Is the photographed liquid tight conduit to the dishwasher? Does the filter/faucet have an ordinary household plug?

Comment: @popham, the conduit is to the garbage disposal. Yes both the filter and the faucet will have standard plugs. The filter is a RO system and the faucet is one of those with motion detection.

Comment: Is the dishwasher outlet directly behind it? Is the dishwasher immediately to the side of the sink like usual? That's probably the place to go for always-on power. Tapping into the dishwasher circuit and surface mounting a 1 or 2 gang box under the sink seems like the path of least resistance.

Comment: @popham , yes the dishwasher immediately to the side. I am unsure where the washers conduit/wiring is located but I will look. Thanks for response!

Comment: I prefer hardwired dishwasher and disposal. After all, how often do you need to disconnect them?

Comment: Your circuit for the disposal may not be even avaiablle if it feeds the switch hot and then only feeds below the cabinet with a switched leg.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease , i've added more photos in the link. Thank you! From the picture I believe there may be some spare hot wire connections behind the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be anywhere from super-easy to moderately hard to impossible.

There are two key issues in being able to tap into the existing circuit:

##### Existing Load

If a circuit has hardwired equipment using more than 50% of the rated circuit capacity then you can't add general purpose receptacles. It doesn't matter that they are under the sink - they are still places you could plug in anything. Check the specs on the disposal and the size of the circuit. If it uses more than 7.5A on a 15A circuit or 10A on a 20A circuit then I believe you are out of luck. A badger 5 1/2 HP is rated at 6.3A. I found a GE 1 HP that is rated at 7.0A. So you may be just fine, but you need to check.

Sharing with the dishwasher is much more likely to be a problem. First GE I looked at 7.8A, so OK on 20A circuit but not on 15A circuit. Found a Bosch at 12A. So it really varies quite a bit.

##### Wiring

This is where it gets tricky. Basically the wiring could be:

- Panel -> junction box under sink near disposal -> switch

in which case you have hot/neutral/switched hot in the box and hot/switched hot at the switch and you can put another box in next to the existing box (or possibly use the existing box) and put in an always on, GFCI protected (i.e., need GFCI here unless already protected at the breaker) duplex receptacle.

Or you could have:

- Panel -> switch -> junction box under sink near disposal

in which case you most likely only have switched hot and neutral under the sink and would need to replace the existing cable between the switch and the box under the sink in order to get always hot.

Impossible to guess what you have. Need to open up the box and take a look.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to see if the cable from box is easily accessible. The breaker is 20A on both disposer and dishwasher- neither are above 50% after looking at labels.

Comment: Here are photos after removing things - seems all the wiring i need is behind the switch on wall. https://imgur.com/a/8MShyGG

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to replace the disposal with one with an integral magnetic switch in the stopper, then bypass the existing switch and you will have unswitched power for everything.

Another way is to use the existing cable to pull a new one from the switch box with one more wire.  May be possible without wall damage.